# Extracing name / value pairs for second-level XML nodes

Tags: php, xml, loops, simplexml, extract

OK, I have some basic XML in the following format:

```
<application>
   <authentication>
      <id>26</id>
      <key>gabe</key>
   </authentication>
   <home>
      <address>443 Pacific Avenue</address>
      <city>North Las Vegas</city>
      <state>NV</state>
      <zip>89084</zip>
   </home>
</application>
```

I am loading the above XML into a variable using simplexml_load_string(), as follows:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
```

I am wanting to extract out the name / value pairs of the second nodes, for example, I want to ignore the `<authentication>` and `<home>` nodes. I am only interest in the children nodes inside of these first-level nodes:

1. id
2. key
3. address
4. city
5. state
6. zip

So I am looking for a foreach loop that will extract out the above 6 name / value pairs but ignore the "lower level" name/value pairs.  The below code only prints the name/value pair for the `<authentication>` and `<home>` nodes (which I want to ignore):

```
foreach($xml->children() as $value) {
  $name = chop($value->getName());
  print "$name = $value";
}
```

Can someone help me out with the code that will extract out **ONLY** the name/value pairs for the 6 nodes mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath:
http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

With the path

```
/application/*/*
```

You will get all second level elements.

EDIT:

```
$string = <<<XML
<application>
   <authentication>
      <id>26</id>
      <key>gabe</key>
   </authentication>
       <home>
          <address>443 Pacific Avenue</address>
          <city>North Las Vegas</city>
          <state>NV</state>
          <zip>89084</zip>
       </home>
    </application>
XML;

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

   foreach($xml->xpath('/application/*/*') as $node){
        echo "{$node->getName()}: $node,\n";
   }
```

Comment: I am still not able to extract out the corresponding name of the second level elements, only the value.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I reviewed your suggestion (Oliver A.) and came up with the following code:

```
$string = <<<XML
<application>
   <authentication>
      <id>26</id>
      <key>gabe</key>
   </authentication>
   <home>
      <address>443 Pacific Avenue</address>
      <city>North Las Vegas</city>
      <state>NV</state>
      <zip>89084</zip>
   </home>
</application>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

/* Search for <a><b><c> */
$result = $xml->xpath('/application/*/*');

while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
    echo '/application/*/*: ',$node,"\n";
}
```

Which returns the following:

```
/application/*/*: 26
/application/*/*: gabe
/application/*/*: 443 Pacific Avenue
/application/*/*: North Las Vegas
/application/*/*: NV
/application/*/*: 89084
```

Which is progress because I now have the values for the second-level elements only.  Great!  The issue is that I am needing to assign a variable name to the name and value pairs.  It seems like I am not able to extract out the name of each second-level node.  Am I missing something?

Comment: xpath returnes simple xml elemnts. If you use them as strings you will only see the inner value, but yu can use object methods on them. Try "$node->getName()"